# CSF not blocking port when removed from csf.conf

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I have removed `VNC` port `5901` from the `csf.conf` configuration file and executed a `csf -f` a `csf -x` and a `csf -e` to flush and restart `CSF`.

There is a `vncserver` running on port `5901` and when doing an `nmap -p 5901 MYIP` from a computer that is NOT in the `csf.allow` file I get a

```
5901/tcp open  vnc-1
```

I then issued the following commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -j DROP
systemctl restart iptables
```

Now when doing an `nmap -p 5901 MYIP` I get the following:

```
5901/tcp closed  vnc-1
```

The `vncserver` is still listening - but now traffic is being blocked. Great, this is expected.

I would like to know why `CSF` is not blocking this port by default? It is my understanding that `CSF` will block all ports that are not set in the `ALLOW INCOMING` section of the `csf.conf`

Here is the output of `csf -l`:

```
# csf -l
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
2        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
6        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
8       15  1568 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
9    11269  682K LOCALINPUT  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10      50  3627 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11   11075  666K INVALID    tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
12   11063  666K ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
13       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:20
14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:21
15       1    48 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25
16       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:53
17      17   884 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:80
18       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:110
19       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:143
20       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:443
21       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:465
22       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:587
23       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:993
24       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:995
25       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:2222
26       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8023
27      14   800 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25565
28       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8080
29       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:64738
30       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpts:25000:25002
31       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8081
32       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8888
33       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:7777
34       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:20
35       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:21
36       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:53
37       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpts:25000:25003
38       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:8081
39       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:8888
40       5   420 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
41       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
42       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
43       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
44       1    35 LOGDROPIN  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4              tcp dpt:53
2        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4              udp dpt:53
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4              tcp spt:53
4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.4.4              udp spt:53
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8              tcp dpt:53
6       15   968 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8              udp dpt:53
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8              tcp spt:53
8        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8              udp spt:53
9    13429 8347K LOCALOUTPUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
11       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
12       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
13       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
14      50  3627 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
15   13116 8271K INVALID    tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
16   13118 8275K ACCEPT     all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
17       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:20
18       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:21
19       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25
20       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:53
21       6   288 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:80
22       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:110
23       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:113
24       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:443
25       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:587
26       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:993
27       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:995
28       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:2222
29       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8023
30       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25565
31       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8080
32       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:64738
33       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpts:25000:25003
34       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8081
35       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:8888
36       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:7777
37       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:20
38       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:21
39       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:53
40       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:113
41       5   380 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:123
42       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpts:25000:25003
43       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:8081
44       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:8888
45       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
46       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
47       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
48       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
49     162 23019 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ALLOWIN (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       ** EDITED OUT **     0.0.0.0/0
2      173 14448 ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       ** EDITED OUT **     0.0.0.0/0

Chain ALLOWOUT (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            ** EDITED OUT **
2      156 52520 ACCEPT     all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            ** EDITED OUT **

Chain DENYIN (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       84.13.41.77          0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       115.239.228.14       0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       183.136.216.4        0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       61.174.51.223        0.0.0.0/0
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       82.98.168.5          0.0.0.0/0
6        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       218.2.0.133          0.0.0.0/0
7        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       149.255.172.10       0.0.0.0/0
8        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       175.139.182.66       0.0.0.0/0
9        0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       122.225.109.216      0.0.0.0/0
10       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       115.239.228.9        0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       61.174.50.188        0.0.0.0/0
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       115.239.228.6        0.0.0.0/0
13       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       61.174.49.106        0.0.0.0/0
14       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       122.225.109.126      0.0.0.0/0
15       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       198.11.235.58        0.0.0.0/0
16       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       168.235.156.205      0.0.0.0/0
17       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.68        0.0.0.0/0
18       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       115.231.223.170      0.0.0.0/0
19       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.12        0.0.0.0/0
20       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       92.29.74.30          0.0.0.0/0
21       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       72.94.20.202         0.0.0.0/0
22       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.165.91        0.0.0.0/0
23       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.127       0.0.0.0/0
24       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.202       0.0.0.0/0
25       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.165.62        0.0.0.0/0
26       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       2.96.208.250         0.0.0.0/0
27       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.170       0.0.0.0/0
28       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.165.16        0.0.0.0/0
29       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       58.137.224.98        0.0.0.0/0
30       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       60.251.70.8          0.0.0.0/0
31       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       41.193.53.71         0.0.0.0/0
32       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       59.120.39.44         0.0.0.0/0
33       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       80.153.119.29        0.0.0.0/0
34       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       109.190.67.128       0.0.0.0/0
35       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.216       0.0.0.0/0
36       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       41.224.253.236       0.0.0.0/0
37       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       81.248.108.219       0.0.0.0/0
38       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.110       0.0.0.0/0
39       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.165.232       0.0.0.0/0
40       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       81.134.7.168         0.0.0.0/0
41       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.171       0.0.0.0/0
42       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       61.40.192.56         0.0.0.0/0
43       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       173.208.194.38       0.0.0.0/0
44       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.100       0.0.0.0/0
45       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       71.94.237.138        0.0.0.0/0
46       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.64        0.0.0.0/0
47       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       93.174.93.181        0.0.0.0/0
48       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       188.29.164.200       0.0.0.0/0
49       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       195.138.249.11       0.0.0.0/0
50       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       69.73.180.238        0.0.0.0/0
51       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       74.208.8.229         0.0.0.0/0
52       3   144 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       74.208.43.32         0.0.0.0/0
53       3   176 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       148.245.192.36       0.0.0.0/0
54       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       177.139.215.107      0.0.0.0/0
55       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       1.23.26.27           0.0.0.0/0
56       0     0 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       207.109.141.56       0.0.0.0/0

Chain DENYOUT (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            84.13.41.77
2        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            115.239.228.14
3        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            183.136.216.4
4        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            61.174.51.223
5        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            82.98.168.5
6        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            218.2.0.133
7        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            149.255.172.10
8        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            175.139.182.66
9        0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            122.225.109.216
10       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            115.239.228.9
11       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            61.174.50.188
12       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            115.239.228.6
13       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            61.174.49.106
14       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            122.225.109.126
15       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            198.11.235.58
16       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            168.235.156.205
17       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.68
18       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            115.231.223.170
19       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.12
20       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            92.29.74.30
21       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            72.94.20.202
22       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.165.91
23       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.127
24       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.202
25       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.165.62
26       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            2.96.208.250
27       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.170
28       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.165.16
29       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            58.137.224.98
30       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            60.251.70.8
31       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            41.193.53.71
32       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            59.120.39.44
33       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            80.153.119.29
34       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            109.190.67.128
35       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.216
36       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            41.224.253.236
37       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            81.248.108.219
38       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.110
39       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.165.232
40       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            81.134.7.168
41       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.171
42       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            61.40.192.56
43       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            173.208.194.38
44       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.100
45       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            71.94.237.138
46       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.64
47       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            93.174.93.181
48       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            188.29.164.200
49       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            195.138.249.11
50       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            69.73.180.238
51       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            74.208.8.229
52       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            74.208.43.32
53       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            148.245.192.36
54       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            177.139.215.107
55       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            1.23.26.27
56       0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            207.109.141.56

Chain INVALID (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 INVDROP    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
2        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
3        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
4        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x03/0x03
5        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
6        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x05/0x05
7        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x11/0x01
8        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x18/0x08
9        0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x30/0x20
10       0     0 INVDROP    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW

Chain INVDROP (10 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOCALINPUT (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    11269  682K ALLOWIN    all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    11096  668K DENYIN     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOCALOUTPUT (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    13429 8347K ALLOWOUT   all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    13273 8295K DENYOUT    all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOGDROPIN (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
2        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
3        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:68
4        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
5        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:111
6        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111
7        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:113
8        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:113
9        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:135:139
10       0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:135:139
11       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
12       0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:445
13       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:500
14       0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:500
15       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:513
16       0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:513
17       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:520
18       0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:520
19       0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
20       1    35 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* "
21       0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* "
22       1    35 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOGDROPOUT (57 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       54  2592 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* "
2       59 10818 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* "
3        0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* "
4      162 23019 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 47 packets, 2619 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 40 packets, 2264 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 182 packets, 24283 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 1264 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

An explanation as to why CSF is behaving like this would be greatly appreciated.